# Why can't I move my weapons individually?

Tags: mechwarrior-online

I feel like I can barely move my weapons. Is there a way to move them individually from the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply hold shift while moving your mouse. If you don't want to have to press shift all the time, disable Arm Lock.